# Web.config: Specify a file location

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload, web-config, filepath

I have a problem with web.config, I am a newbie. And i don't know how to get the filepath into btn_uploadFile_Click. Here's my web.config filepath

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="IncidentPath" value="C:\Netserve\Incident\"/>
    <add key="ContractPath" value="C:\Netserve\Contract\"/>
  </appSettings>
```

And vb code. I don't want to use the savePath variable. I want to retrieve the folder path from web.config, and after that I want to check whether the path is valid. Is that possible? How to do that?

```
Protected Sub btn_uploadFile_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btn_uploadFile.Click
        Try
            Dim savePath As String = "c:\Netserve\Incident\" & Me.in01_txt_incidentNo.Text & "\"


            If Not IO.Directory.Exists(savePath) Then
                IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(savePath)
            End If
            If (FileUpload1.HasFile) Then
                ' Get the name of the file to upload.
                Dim fileName As String = FileUpload1.FileName

                While IO.File.Exists(savePath & fileName)
                    fileName = "C" & fileName
                End While


                savePath += fileName

                FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath)

                saveFiletoDB(savePath, fileName)
            Else
                ' Notify the user that a file was not uploaded.
                ShareVar.dd_error("You did not specify a file to upload.")
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            ShareVar.dd_error(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: Use relevant paths (~/folder/file.txt) not absolute paths like c:\..

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` to your project (if it's not already added) and add `Imports System.Configuration` to your imports statements in the code behind.
2. Use [ConfigurationManager.AppSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) to read the values from the `<appSettings>` section of the .config file